# Prevent successive comments from users PHP

Tags: php

Hi I am wondering how to do the first if statement. The rest works as expected (although longwinded) not sure how to optimise that, but that's for another time. What I need is to give an error message if a user attempts to post twice in succession.

Thank you

```
function saveCommentToDatabase($stack, $name, $comment)
    {   
        if($name == previousauthor){
            return 'Can\'t post twice';
        }
        else if(!$name){ 
            return 'You seem to have an existential problem. You do not exist.';
        }
        else if($name == 'Charles Dickens'){
            return 'You are NOT Charles Dickens.';
        }
        else if($name == 'Author'){
            return 'You should try being a little more imaginative with your name.'; 
        }
        else if($name == 'password1'){
           $name = 'User One'; 
        }   
        else if($name == 'password2'){
           $name = 'User Two'; 
        }   
        else if($name == 'password3'){
           $name = 'User Three'; 
        }
              else if($name == 'password4'){
           $name = 'User Four'; 
        }
```

Comment: You could move all your `else if`'s into a [`switch-case`](http://php.net/switch) construction to make it a little less longwinded.

Comment: In this case you can even move most of it into an array.

Comment: I actually want all the if password = x username = y in a separate page which can be accessed from the php page. Will look into switch statements. Thank you Kristian

Comment: It may not be working because `previousauthor` is missing the `$`.

Comment: That's just pseudocode Renesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to fetch comments from whatever store you are using (DB?) and check if name of previous poster matches name of current poster.

You would also want to check time of previous comment and compare it to current time(). If some period of time is already passed, you would let the user to post another comment.

Comment: Thanks mephisto. The time information is not necessary, because no successive posts are allowed. It's kind of a game where you must take turns.

Comment: I have this code on the same php page which shows the comments. So can I check the last comment and who posted it from here?
`$entries .= '<div class="ydss-comment" id="'.$row->id.'"><strong>'.$row->author.'</strong> <em>'.$postdate.'</em>'.$row->message.'</div>';`

Comment: erm, if you have fetched all rows you're going to display, you should have last row. check author of it and you're done.
If you did not yet at the moment you're checking new comment being posted, then you gotta fetch last row from DB. I don't know structure of your DB and application. I can not write code for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie when the user posts, and refuse posts from users with that cookie. Of course, savvy and persistent posters will figure out that they can clear cookies to post again, but if you have that type of users then there are few technical measures that you could take in any case.